# Straightforward way to add timestamp to Firebase in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so I've been researching a lot and apparently no method is working to add timestamp to my firebase data and then sort the data accordingly. I tried the traditional `"timestamp": [".sv":"timestamp"]` method and that only adds a value of `.sv: Timestamp` in firebase. Then I tried `self.createdAt = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp/1000)` and added that to where I add the item to firebase but that didn't help either.So doesn't anyone know what's the most straightforward method to add timestamp to firebase via swift? Would appreciate any input! Thanks.

EDIT:

Here's now I define the item being added to firebase:

```
struct Note: Identifiable, Codable {

var id: String
var content: String
var createdAt: String

 }
```

Here's how I define fetching that item from firebase:

```
func fetchNotes () {

    notes.removeAll()
 
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    let ref = db.collection("userslist").document(uid).collection("actualnotes")
    
    ref.order(by: "createdAt", descending: true).addSnapshotListener{ (querySnapshot, error) in
        let documents = querySnapshot!.documents
        
        if querySnapshot!.isEmpty {
            let ref = db.collection("userslist").document(uid).collection("actualnotes")
            ref.document().setData(["content": "Welcome", "createdAt": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()  ])
        }
        else {
            
        self.notes = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Note in
           let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            let id = queryDocumentSnapshot.documentID
            let content = data["content"] as! String ?? ""
            let createdAt = data["createdAt"] as? String ?? ""         // this is where
   // it breaks with the error (Thread 1: signal SIGABRT)
            
       
            let note = Note(id:id, content:content, createdAt: createdAt)
            
            return (note)
        }
        }
    }
  }
```

And here's where I want the timestamp to appear in another view:

```
   List{ ForEach(dataManager.notes) { note in
                    NavigationLink(destination: NoteView(newNote: note.content, idd: note.id ))
                    {
                        HStack {
                           

                            Text(note.createdAt)
        }})}}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a single snippet of code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem? You might also want to look at this, which is the value you'd need to write: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/ServerValue#/c:objc(cs)FIRServerValue(cm)timestamp

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My bad for the negligence. Just edited it with the error that comes up.

Answer (score 0):

The `[".sv":"timestamp"]` applies to the Realtime Database only, while you are using Cloud Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and the API of one does not apply to the other.

For Firestore follow its documentation on [writing a server-side timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#swift_9), which says it should be:

```
db.collection("objects").document("some-id").updateData([
    "lastUpdated": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
])
```

If that doesn't work, edit your question to show the exact error you get.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I believe I'm using the same function that you listed in my code. I have " "createdAt": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()". Aren't they the same thing ?